# PHP and Session error

Tags: php, session

Hello I have a problem with a session. When I use a session to pass a variable to another page the values of that variable always still the same in the other page. No matter what row I selected. When I change the "action" to the same page where the variable is, the value shows correct. Sorry for my bad English if someone speak Spanish let my know to explain better. I really need help in this.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include_once 'rnheader.php';

session_start();

$ticket_select = $_POST['serviceID'];

echo '<a href = "rnservices.php">  Create Service</a> ';

echo '<table border="1" >';

echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Service ID</th>';
echo '<th>Title</th>';
echo '<th>Description</th>';
echo '<th>Notes</th>';
echo '<th>Submit By</th>';
echo '<th>Assigned Employee</th>';
echo '<th>Assigned Group</th>';
echo '<th>Category</th>';
echo '<th>Status</th>';
echo '<th>Urgency</th>';
echo '<th>Customer</th>';
echo '<th>Day Created</th>';
echo '</tr>';

$query = ("SELECT ServiceID, Title, Description, Notes, SubmitBy, AssignedEmp, " .
"AssignedGroup, NameCategory, TipoStatus, TiposUrgencia, CustomerName, DayCreation FROM Service");
$result = queryMysql($query);



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo '<tr>';

    echo '<td><form method ="post" action="rnservices1.php">';
    ?>
    <input type="submit"  name="serviceID" value=<?php echo $row['ServiceID']?>
    <?php
    echo '</form>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Title'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Notes'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['SubmitBy'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['AssignedEmp'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['AssignedGroup'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['NameCategory'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['TipoStatus'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['TiposUrgencia'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['CustomerName'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['DayCreation'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

echo $ticket_select;
$_SESSION['serviceID'] = $ticket_select;


 '</table>';


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a case issue?

```
$_SESSION['serviceID'] = $ticket_select;
<input type="submit"  name="serviceID" value=<?php echo $row['ServiceID']?>
$ticket_select = $_POST['serviceID'];
```

Notice the middle one has a capital S on ServiceID and the other two are serviceID.

Comment: uery = "SELECT  Title from Service where ServiceID = '$ticket_select'";
    $result = queryMysql($query);
    echo 'Number of Rows: ' . mysql_num_rows($result);
    ?>
    <input type="" id="Title" name="Title" size = "58" value="<?php echo $ticket_select; ?>"/><br/>

<?php

Comment: The value is working when I use echo $ticket_select; but in the page where the variable was created. When I use it in the other page is where the value of the variable dont change.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
$ticket_select = $_SESSION['serviceID'];
destroySession();

Comment: Why are you destroying the session? That's like pouring out the coffee you just bought and complaining you cup's empty.